# PHP Accessing Value from Class

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm new to PHP and i want to understand the following case and how to find a working solution.
I have two script `config.php` and `index.php`

Config.php

```
<?php

$ip = 'localhost';
$username ='patrick';
$password = 'password';

?>
```

Index.php

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
class index extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
private $index;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->index= NULL;
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        $this->index= NULL;
    }

    public function testGetConfig()
    {
        echo $ip // How do I pass the value to this function?
    }

}
?>
```

How do I pass the value from a script to the function in a class.

Comment: You can store your config in an individual class which return it from static function.

Comment: You don't get to pass values to PHPUnit tests (it's all controlled by the framework). You have to load the values in the test method, by moving the require statement into testGetConfig, for instance.

Comment: @Peter, okay that's something new to me.I'm trying to access the value but keep on getting error passing null variable

Comment: Not sure what you mean by getConfig. You have written a method named testGetConfig. If you move the require statement from the global scope into the method, the variables declared in config.php are available in the method.

Comment: @Peter, ah i get it. So let's say if i want to use the same config in multiple function so i just require 'file.php' to each function?

Comment: If you don't control the arguments to the function, yes.

Comment: I'd think requiring the file inside `setUp` and setting the values as object properties makes the most sense, then they're available in all further methods…

Comment: @deceze that makes sense. So my setup function will look like this ?
 protected function setUp()
    {
        require 'config.php';
        $this->upsell = new upSellCore();
        $this->odb_user = $odb_user;
        $this->odb_pass = $odb_pass;
        $this->odb_host = $odb_host;
        $this->odb_name = $odb_name;
    }

Comment: @Peter, so i have to build many private variable to store those value for later on?